# Attempting to run Update Query doesn't update dataset

Tags: c#, sql-update, tableadapter, sqldataadapter

So I have a Database that I created a Dataset from, I'm attempting to run an Update on it and I cannot get it to update the Dataset (and subsequently the Database) with the result.  I built the Query using Visual Studio's query builder and when I run it through there it changes the data in the way that it should.  When I run the code I put in a MessageBox to show the number of rows the query changed and it is returning 1 as it should.  I'm at a loss as to why it won't 'commit' the update and I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.
Here is the Query I setup (named "UpdateQuery")

```
UPDATE Bug_Master
SET Name = @Name, Test_App = @Test_App, Bug_Type = @Bug_Type, Bug_Active = @Bug_Active, Bug_Description = @Bug_Description, Bug_Keywords = @Bug_Keywords
WHERE (Id = @Original_Id);
```

In the Load event for the form I have

```
this.bug_MasterTableAdapter.Fill(this.bugManagerDataSet.Bug_Master);
```

And here is where I am calling the Query and trying to update (I know I should use 'using' but I'll pretty up the code after I get this to work so forgive the inelegance)

```
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            int iResult = bug_MasterTableAdapter.UpdateQuery("Error One 1", "PassVault", "Runtime", "True", "Description Test", "Keywords Test", 1);
            MessageBox.Show(iResult.ToString());
            bug_MasterTableAdapter.Update(bugManagerDataSet.Bug_Master);
            connection.Close();
```

As I mentioned above the MessageBox shows '1'.  Is there a critical step I'm missing on how to do this?  It has been a long time since I messed with SQL so I've had to bumble my way back to it and have no doubt I've missed/messed up some things.
Thanks in advance.
erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  Turns out the 'copy to output directory' property on the database file was set to 'always copy'.  So when I ran the program it would make changes to the database in the \bin\debug folder while I was looking at the one in the app folder.  Then when I would restart the program to check the values in there it would overwrite the changed version of the database in \bin\debug with the unchanged version from the project.
So, the upshot is for anyone else that runs into something similar is set the 'Copy to Output Directory' option on the database to 'Copy if Newer'.
Thanks to all who took a look.

erik